# Why Linux /etc/fstab UUIDs are case sensitive?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, uuid, umount

I recently added a line for a USB memory stick to `/etc/fstab`, to be able to mount it automatically, using UUID to identify the device.

Before I already have several external ext4 drives that have their UUIDs written in lowercase hexadecimal chars `[0-9a-f]` like this:

```
UUID=3eeaaa43-dead-beef-cafe-243bcaaad475 /media/external_2TB ext4 rw,user,noexec,nosuid,nodev,noatime 0 2
```

I checked the UUID of my USB stick with `blkid`, got an uppercase hexadecimal UUID and entered it in `/etc/fstab` in the same way as the ext4 lines, in lowercase hexadecimal, like this:

```
UUID=125c-a3eb  /media/usb_8GB vfat defaults,users,umask=0  0 0

mount: special device UUID=125c-a3eb does not exist
```

Then I got an idea to try it in uppercase (<kbd>gU3w</kbd> in Vim) and it worked without problems. To confirm this, I unmounted, and changed the UUID back to lowercase, mount failed, and back to uppercase, and mounted successfully.

As far as I have understood, UUID is a hexadecimal number, not a string, so the case of letters should be irrelevant. But clearly it's not. [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) defines UUID as "case insensitive on input". Is there something I have missed or is this `mount` / `umount` behavior a bug?

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 Wheezy with a custom kernel version 3.6.8, if that matters.

Comment: UUID is NOT a hexadecimal string, rather UUID is a 128-bit value (a 128-bit integer, if you will). The hexadecimal string used for UUID is only its canonical textual representation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE:** This is speculation, based on how devices are typically accessed in Unix/Linux and the fact that the filenames are case-sensitive.

Linux uses the UUIDs to create objects in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.  Like any "file" on Linux, the name is case sensitive.  Hence when referring to disks by UUID, the comparison is done as a file-name comparison on the hex strings rather than a binary comparison on the data represented by said strings.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of implied by @sparkie's answer, and part of what's going on in the original question, is that the UUIDs for FAT partitions (seem to?) always need to be uppercase (e.g. `UUID=125C-A3EB`) whereas the UUIDs for ext4 partitions always need to be lowercase (e.g. `UUID=3eeaaa43-dead-beef-cafe-243bcaaad475`).

Answer (score 1):

in case of vfat we effectively don't see a full blown UUID. It's a Volume ID (serial number) instead. These of course are not subject to the RFC mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, ext4 UUIDs are also case sensitive. Further, volume IDs are also hexadecimal numbers AFAIK, not strings.